# Having issue with running django server. Keep getting the following error: AttributeError: module 'django.utils.termcolors' has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I am new to Django and this is my first ever project in it. The project was running fine but I am not sure what is happening now as I keep getting the following error when trying to run the server using the command:

```
python3 manage.py runserver
```

Here is the full error I am getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/logging/config.py", line 543, in configure
    formatters[name])
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/logging/config.py", line 654, in configure_formatter
    result = self.configure_custom(config)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/logging/config.py", line 473, in configure_custom
    result = c(**kwargs)
  File "/Users/i320408/Documents/Yadu/Workspace/tutorial/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/log.py", line 166, in __init__
    self.style = color_style()
  File "/Users/i320408/Documents/Yadu/Workspace/tutorial/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/color.py", line 72, in color_style
    return make_style(os.environ.get('DJANGO_COLORS', ''))
  File "/Users/i320408/Documents/Yadu/Workspace/tutorial/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/color.py", line 44, in make_style
    format = color_settings.get(role, {})
AttributeError: module 'django.utils.termcolors' has no attribute 'get'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/i320408/Documents/Yadu/Workspace/tutorial/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 357, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "/Users/i320408/Documents/Yadu/Workspace/tutorial/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/i320408/Documents/Yadu/Workspace/tutorial/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 19, in setup
    configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
  File "/Users/i320408/Documents/Yadu/Workspace/tutorial/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/log.py", line 71, in configure_logging
    logging.config.dictConfig(DEFAULT_LOGGING)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/logging/config.py", line 800, in dictConfig
    dictConfigClass(config).configure()
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/logging/config.py", line 546, in configure
    'formatter %r' % name) from e
ValueError: Unable to configure formatter 'django.server'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/i320408/Documents/Yadu/Workspace/tutorial/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/i320408/Documents/Yadu/Workspace/tutorial/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 370, in execute
    _parser = self.fetch_command('runserver').create_parser('django', 'runserver')
  File "/Users/i320408/Documents/Yadu/Workspace/tutorial/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 244, in fetch_command
    klass = load_command_class(app_name, subcommand)
  File "/Users/i320408/Documents/Yadu/Workspace/tutorial/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 38, in load_command_class
    return module.Command()
  File "/Users/i320408/Documents/Yadu/Workspace/tutorial/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 240, in __init__
    self.style = color_style(force_color)
  File "/Users/i320408/Documents/Yadu/Workspace/tutorial/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/color.py", line 72, in color_style
    return make_style(os.environ.get('DJANGO_COLORS', ''))
  File "/Users/i320408/Documents/Yadu/Workspace/tutorial/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/color.py", line 44, in make_style
    format = color_settings.get(role, {})
AttributeError: module 'django.utils.termcolors' has no attribute 'get'
```

Comment: Have you activated your virtual environment where all packages are installed using pip before running the server with runserver?

Comment: Hi Marco,
The venv is running and activated. I am not able to run any command in my venv, it gives me this same error. I tried installing django again and it gave me this same error again.

Comment: So I tried doing a pip update in the venv and the same error happened again. The whole venv is not usable anymore.

Comment: You should create a new one (`python3 -m venv venv`) and install all necessary packages again. Then use `pip freeze > requirements.txt` to generate a package list with all installed packages for later use. Or if you already have one: Create a new virtual environment and install from the requirements file `pip install -r requirements.txt`

Comment: Thank you for this Marco, I created the new virtual environment as you suggested and the freeze command is just brilliant.